# Stratio cassandra maxClauseCount is set to 1024

Tags: cassandra, lucene, stratio, cassandra-lucene-index

I am using lucene index for Cassandra.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.stratio.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-lucene-index-builder</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: maxClauseCount is set to 1024
```

due to too many filter conditions. I have read that we can increase the limits, I was wondering how can I increase the limit? I tried using BooleanQuery, but it is not found. Is that the way to increase ? Which dependency can I use for that?

Answer (score 0):

I think that in Lucene, specifically in [Boolean queries](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_4/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html) this limit exists to force users to be aware of misuse.

User @user1860447 opened an issue [#333](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/issues/332) in our github, and we [added a max_clause field](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/pull/338) in cassandra-lucene-index boolean queries to let you modify this limit but you must be sure to test your systems.

You can read more about [this limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502947/what-are-the-limitations-of-boolean-query-in-lucene)